# Cannot push rasa app into heroku container

Tags: docker, dockerfile, rasa, rasa-nlu

I am trying to deploy rasa app on heroku and docker, I have successfully logged in with container but while running following command I am getting an error

```
sudo heroku container:push web
```

**Error**

```
Error: Missing required flag:
›    -a, --app APP  app to run command against
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM ubuntu:18.04
ENTRYPOINT []

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y python3.7 python3-pip

RUN pip3 install --upgrade --no-cache pip3==20.2
RUN python3 -m pip install --no-cache rasa==2.8.26

ADD . /app/

RUN chmod +x /app/start_services.sh
CMD /app/start_services.sh 

RUN chmod +x /app/start_action_service.sh
CMD /app/start_action_service.sh
```

**start_services.sh**

```
cd app/
#Start rasa server with nlu model
rasa run --model models --enable-api --cors "*" --debug \
         -p $PORT
```

**start_action_service.sh**

```
cd app/
#Start action server
rasa run actions \
     -p $PORT
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must specify the application name like this

`heroku container:push web --app YOUR_APP_NAME`

And then release the app with

`heroku container:release web --app YOUR_APP_NAME`